# UITextField - delegate for clearButtonMode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want the X button to show only when

```
textField.clearButtonMode = .UnlessEditing
```

When the user pushes the X button, the textView becomes the first responder, and the keyboard pops up.

What do I do so that when the X button is pushed, the text only clears, but the textView does not become focused?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this delegate like the following:

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.text = ""     

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be focus and able to key in, try

`textField.becomeFirstResponder()`

If you mean you want it not to show the keyboard and just clear the text, you can delegate your UITextField and use the function to return false:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.text = ""
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
```

this method is your want,you can check something in it.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW10
 i hope above link can help you.